# How do I discover what gems my code is using (aka create a post-facto Gemfile)?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I started out writing a little hack and did a few "gem install xxx" along the way.  Now the little hack has grown large, I don't recall all the gems I've installed and, for portability, I'd like to create a Gemfile that specifies the required gems.

Is there a reliable way to find out what gems my app is using so I can specify them in a Gemfile?  I can create a fresh environment, run it, and see what breaks.  But perhaps there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monkey-patching and good test suite are your friends. Use this:

```
module Kernel
  alias_method :old_require, :require
  def require(name)
    puts name
    old_require(name)
  end
end
```

And run your test.

Comment: Looks good.  Perhaps I should keep a level count as well; I'm interested in the toplevel gems that my code requires, not so interested in the lower-level dependencies.  (Presumably the dependencies are accurately in the gemspecs.)  Agreed?